# Запрос ElemMatch в MondoDb (C#, драйвер 2.0)

Tags: c#, база-данных, orm, mongodb, nosql

Пытаюсь сделать запрос для поиска записей у которых поле (которое является массивом) содержит заданную строку:

```
var builder = Builders<ProductModelDb>.Filter;
var eqFilter = Builders<string>.Filter.Eq(x => x, "\nHome");
var matchFilter = builder.ElemMatch<string>(x=>x.productData.Breadcams, eqFilter);
var res = productCollection.Find(matchFilter).ToListAsync().Result;
```

модель данных такая:

```
public class ProductModelDb
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Url;
    public DateTime DateTime;
    public ProductDataModel productData;
}

public class ProductDataModel   
{        
    public List<string> Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Breadcams { get; set; }
}
```

При выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: fieldName
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.Ensure.IsNotNull[String] (System.String value, System.String paramName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.RenderedFieldDefinition`1[System.String]..ctor (System.String fieldName, IBsonSerializer`1 fieldSerializer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition`2[System.String,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.SimpleFilterDefinition`2[System.String,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.ElementMatchFilterDefinition`2[DataModels.ProductModelDb,System.String].Render (IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb].FindAsync[ProductModelDb] (MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition`1 filter, MongoDB.Driver.FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2[DataModels.ProductModelDb,DataModels.ProductModelDb].ToCursorAsync (CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions+<ToListAsync>d__14`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataModels.ProductModelDb]].get_Result () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at DataBaseProcesser.CategoryProcessor.CreateCategory () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at DataBaseProcesser.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--> (Inner exception 0) System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

В чем моя ошибка? Как правильно писать запросы ElemMatch?

Comment: Что мешает дебажить порграмму, когда возникло исключение?

Comment: В отладке тоже самое, при вызове _Result_ выбрасывает `System.AggregateException` внутри которого исключение  `Value cannot be null. Имя параметра: fieldName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вот тут: `Builders<string>.Filter.Eq(x => x, "\nHome");` Лямбда-выражение обязательно должно указывать на поле - то есть писать `x => x` тут недопустимо.

Можно попробовать написать что-нибудь вроде `builder.ElemMatch(x => x.productData.Breadcams, x => x == "\nHome");` - т. е. отказаться от использования вложенного фильтра.

---

Но, вообще говоря, надо смотреть документацию по MondoDb - а она говорит, что оператор [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) в таких простых случаях применять не следует. Вместо этого надо применять оператор [$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#op._S_eq).

Получается что-то вроде:

```
Builders<ProductModelDb>.Filter.AnyEq(x => x.productData.Breadcams, "\nHome")
```